# Comparing values return from database against values returned by json

Tags: php, mysql, database, json

So I have a database that contains over a thousand urls. I am running an application using which you can add more values to the database.

There is a form in the application using which you can add more values to the database. Once you submit the form it converts the form values to json, then it performs a few functions on those values and eventually they are supposed to end up in database.

Now inorder to save space I dont want any duplicates in the database. Is there a fast way to compare every value in the json, returned by the from, to every value in the url_column of the database.

Note: You can enter more than one urls in the form. On average every time the form is submitted it returns 10 urls encoded in json.
I am using php. but i dont care about the language, just looking for an efficient solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the url_column unique in the database, so any insertion of dupe values will be rejected